# How to avoid Jitter on a LAN network?

Tags: networking, ping, latency, packet-loss, data-loss-prevention

I recently acquired fiber connection at home, but I faced an issue, every 10 minutes, the connection kinda stop and then restart. Which cause websites or any software that require internet connection to crash/wait during around 1 minute.

This is annoying. So I started investigating.

### Step 1: ping command

I ran a simple ping command for few entires days:

```
ping -t www.google.com
```

The result was clear: I never saw any problem or increasing ping:

[image: ping command]

So at first as I didn't have any clue, I started asking myself if I was crazy or not, if thoses application really stuck for few secondes every 10 minutes.

**They did and they still do.**

---

### Step 2: Using Ethernet cables

Then as I was using a [Power-line communication (PLC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication), for a computer, and WiFi for an other one. I unpluged the PLC, desactivated the WiFi and bought a 25-meter ethernet cable running through the entire house in order to plug my computer exclusively using cables.

**Nothing changed**: stable ping but still some Jitter and connection that I could see but not identify.

---

### Step 3: pingplotter

Then I dowloaded and installed [pingplotter](https://www.pingplotter.com/). Which graphs latency and packet loss between a computer and a target website or server.

The result obtained in the following:

[image: pingplotter]

As you can see on the image above, the ping increase slitly, but not enough to make a websote or a software disconnect itself.

The interesting part is the **Jitter (ms)** that appear at 6-minutes of intervals.

[image: Jitter (ms)]

I'm sure this is the cause of all my stuggles.

Do you have any ideas how to fix/avoid it ? Or even what it is ? What's causing this ?

Thanks in advance !

---

FAQ

What do you mean by "Jitter" ?

> slight irregular movement, variation, or unsteadiness, especially in
>   an electrical signal or electronic device.

Comment: What do you mean by stop and restart? Does the Ethernet connection drop?  Can you still ping Google when this happens?

Comment: Do you see any jitter if you ping the ISP gateway?

Comment: @RonTrunk The Ethernet connection is still connected and the ping to google perfectly works when this happens (see Step 1). I haven't tried to ping the ISP gateway i'll check this monday evening and give you some feedback.

Comment: @RonTrunk I did tests as promised. I couldn't find how to ping the ISP gateway, so I pinged both my Public IPv4 address (which I suppose is also the ISP?) and my local IP, none of them has any jitter while www.google.com does.
If I can provide any more information feel free to ask me, this problem is very important to me and I feel like my post don't have enough attention.

Comment: There’s very little you can do about the jitter. The Internet gives no guarantees regarding performance.   1 minute interruptions, however, should be taken up with your ISP.

Comment: The problem is that ISP don't really care about it, do you think leaving this one and taking another ISP could solve the issue ? Also can it depend on the router the ISP provided ?

Comment: @RonTrunk Also I noticed that I am able to produce high Jitter easily if I update or download any software. If this may help